# Load json file with KnockoutJS and Jade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, knockout.js, pug

I have a json file that I am loading via an api. The json file will be an array of stores. When I load the page this is the error I am getting in the stacktrace:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return stores }"
Message: stores is not defined
```

This is what the json that is coming back from the API looks like:

```
[
    {
        "store_name": "Aber",
        "store_wiki_folder": "#F",
        "store_wiki_contact": "#C",
        "store_wiki_access": "#A",
        "store_db": "db:127.2.3.1:9000",
        "sites": [
            {
                "label": "Prod",
                "link": "http://google.com",
                "special_label": "[Admin]",
                "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
            },

            {
                "label": "Train",
                "link": "http://google.com",
                "special_label": "[Admin]",
                "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "store_name": "Academy",
        "store_wiki_folder": "#F",
        "store_wiki_contact": "#C",
        "store_wiki_access": "#A",
        "store_db": "db:127.2.3.1:9000",
        "sites": [
            {
                "label": "Live",
                "link": "http://google.com",
                "special_label": "[Admin]",
                "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
            },

            {
                "label": "Test",
                "link": "http://google.com",
                "special_label": "[Admin]",
                "special_link": "http://images.google.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is what I have to pull from the api and do the ko bindings:

```
$.getJSON("/api/stores", function(stores) {
    var storesModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(stores);
    ko.applyBindings(storesModel);
})
```

I am using Jade for building my layouts:

```
extends layout

block content
   .container(role="main")
       .row
           .col-md-12
               ul(data-bind="foreach:stores")
                   li(data-bind="text: store_name")
```

I am thinking it could be related to the way I structured my json file. The structure of the json file can be changed.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What goes wrong? What errors do you get in console?

Comment: Could you please rephrase it? I don't undestand you at all.

Comment: Olga, updated original post to add error from console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"foreach:stores"` assumes you have a `stores` property in the model.
What you show is just an array without that, so you need something like:

`ko.applyBindings({ stores: storesModel });`

Comment: So that got rid of the error but now I see no content in my ul. <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><ul data-bind="foreach:stores"></ul></div></div>

Comment: If I console.log(storesModel) the console window shows function d()

Comment: Hard to say from here, but you may want to try "foreach:stores()".  Also try
`var storesModel = JSON.parse(stores)` as a test instead of the mapping plugin.  Also may want to try use this extension to what data is being bound to DOM: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Instead of ko.mapping.fromJSON(stores), I changed it to ko.mapping.fromJS(stores). That did the trick